# Open fancybox 2.1.4 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a div with the id #popupContent. It has some text inside and also loads some modules via php, everything is working fine if i assign this box to an a tag. But now i want to open it via javascript but how do i do that.. the documentation si really confusing.

As i said i am on fancybox 2.1.4, for now i tried to use

```
<div id="popupContent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col...>
      <h2> bla bla bla </h2>
    </div
  </div>
</div
```

i tried to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        $.fancybox($('#popupContent'));
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the gallery grid to your code. Also, please add the JavaScript that initializes the fancybox on page load. [The API documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) mentions an `open() method`. That may all you need.

Comment: Don't need to wrap your script in a function wrapper like `(function(){...})()`, use a regular jQuery document `ready` method. http://jsfiddle.net/kxq77rkk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a button and call the function like so-

```
<button id="popUpOpenButton" onClick="myFunction()">
```

And then

```
function myFunction(){
 $.fancybox($('#popUpOpenButton'));
}
```